# Converting a birthdate into milliseconds

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

How do I take a birthdate entered by a user and turn into milliseconds so that I can calculate how old they would be on a different planet

Here is the code I have so far:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy");
Date dateBirth = df.parse(birthdate);
Calendar calBirth = new GregorianCalendar();
calBirth.setTime(dateBirth);
```

Edit 1: Yes I'm looking to get the milliseconds between the user's birthdate and the current time in order to divide that by a planet's days in a year

Comment: Do you _really_ require milliseconds? That seems a little too fine a precision for calculating an age, don't you think?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking for the milliseconds between the user's birthdate and the current time?

Comment: That would make more sense than my answer.  I guess it took me a while to wrap my head around the "age on another planet" theme - I guess if you know the number of milliseconds per year on Mars, say, you can divide your current age in milliseconds by that factor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[dateBirth.getTime()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) will give you the number of milliseconds since the epoch, if that's what you're looking for?

EDIT -

In order to get the difference between now and the birthday, you can obviously just get now as a Date object, convert that to milliseconds, and subtract - eg `now.GetTime() - dateBirth.GetTime()`.

Comment: You beat me to the answer, but I'm leaving mine up since you failed to make any time travel jokes in yours.

Comment: What's with all the capitalization of the first letters of methods in a question about Java?

Comment: @jball, +1 for you because I didn't have the guts to make the joke.  @ColinD, that's what happens after I answer a Java question after spending all day programming in C#.

Answer (score 6):

```
Date d = new Date();
long msSinceBirth = d.getTime() - dateBirth.getTime();
```

This assumes the user is born in the past. Time travellers will produce negative values for `msSinceBirth`.

Comment: No +1 - time travel joke not up to required standard.

Comment: @Stephen, if I could go back in time and write a better one, I would.

Comment: Paradoxically, the "edit" button means that you don't need to go back in time to write a better joke  :-)

Comment: @Stephen, going back in time would be the trivial part. It's the other half of the problem that I can't solve.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure I fully understand the question, but Calendar has the method right in it...

`getTimeInMillis`

`public long getTimeInMillis()`

Gets this Calendar's current time as a long.

Returns:
the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch.

See Also:
`getTime(), setTimeInMillis(long)`